# Passing iterator value to Sqlite3 like condition of select clause in python

Tags: python, sqlite, ipython

I have a code as below

```
inPath = 'D:\\maddy'
outPath = 'D:\\maddy\\corpora'
fileName = 'genrelist.txt'
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as connection,open(os.path.join(inPath, fileName), "r") as inputFile:
    myFileReader = csv.reader(inputFile)
    c = connection.cursor()
    for genre in myFileReader:
        '''store output in files named after each genre'''
        with open(os.path.join(outPath,'%s.txt' %genre[0]), "w") as outputFile:
            my_file_writer = csv.writer(outputFile,delimiter=",",quotechar="'")  
            c.execute("SELECT Plot FROM Movies WHERE Genre LIKE '%genre%' " )
            my_file_writer.writerows(c.fetchall())
```

Here the genrelist consists the names of various genres like

Action
Adventure
Crime
Drama
.
.
.
.

When I am trying to iterate over the loop using the genre read the file,I am not able to pass this value to the LIKE condition in SELECT clause as it is treating it as a string rather than variable with dynamic value.

Request you to please help me how to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Maddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to pass variables to sql is :

```
 c.execute("SELECT Plot FROM Movies WHERE Genre LIKE ? ",('%'+genre+'%',) )
```

Comment: You'll need to do more than that; you need to add the `%` wildcards too.

Comment: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: it is giving the above the error

Comment: @martijn Pieters oops, updated.

Comment: c.execute("SELECT Plot FROM Movies WHERE Genre LIKE %s",("%" + genre[0] + "%",))
-- then there is "near "%": syntax error " - Error

Comment: @AlanHoover: You can't do that; the `%` have to be concatenated to the *value*, not to the placeholder. See the dupe.

Comment: @AlanHoover: yup, now you match my answer on the dupe. :-P

Comment: ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied. (error for updated code) I have used genre[0] ...

Comment: @AlanHoover: also, `genre` is a CSV row, so a list.

Comment: @maddy: that sounds like you don't have the `?` placeholder in the `SELECT`.